# What is a Mongoose Query object ? Is it a promise?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Mongoose models provide several static helper functions for CRUD operations. Each of these functions returns a mongoose *Query object*.

For example :

```
    let query = Model.find();
```

This returns a `<Query>` Object which is chainable.

```js
    async function() => {
        let newQuery = query.where("key").equals("value");
        let result = await newQuery;
    }
```

Q1• What exactly is a Query Object returned from `Model.find()`?

Q2• How does chaining work?

**Are `<Query>` objects like promise since I am using asynchronous functions?**

Kindly link any kind of docs that might clear my issue ?
I am relatively new to this so if my question makes no sense please correct me :-(

Answer (score 3):

For questions like these, it is best to consult the TypeScript definitions for the module. [query.d.ts](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/types/query.d.ts) in particular holds the answers.

> Q1• What exactly is a Query Object returned from Model.find()?

`find`'s signature looks as follows:

```
find<ResultDoc = HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals>>(
      callback?: Callback<ResultDoc[]> | undefined
    ): QueryWithHelpers<Array<ResultDoc>, ResultDoc, TQueryHelpers, T>;
```

So the return type is `QueryWithHelpers` with some generics, which resolves to `Query` with some generics. Now to look at it's definition it is quite long. It is a regular object with the following implementations:

- interfaces to call `exec()`, `find()`, `findOne`, etc. These are your chaining methods (Q2).
- It implements an async iterator: `[Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<DocType>;` which lets you use things like `for (let .. of ..)` on it
- It implements an interface to work like a promise: `then: Promise<ResultType>['then'];`. This lets you do `find(...).then(...)`, which is the same thing the `await` keyword does, which makes it work as well.